# Можно ли узнать имя css файла по имени класса с определенным правилом из JS

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Например имеем `HTML` страницу с подключенными к ней несколькими файлами стилей `CSS`
В одном одни правила, в другом другие.
Можно ли при помощи `JavaScript` по имени сласса например узнать в каком именно из этих `CSS` файлов прописаны определенные правила?

Answer (score 2):

Ну, примерно так:

```js
$(function() {

  var cssfile;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {

    var ss = document.styleSheets[i];
    var rules = ss.cssRules || ss.rules;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
      var rule = rules[i];

      //ищем h1
      if (/(^|,) *h1 *(,|$)/i.test(rule.selectorText)) {
          cssfile=ss
      }
    }

  }

  //возвращает null, тк. встроенный стиль
  console.log(cssfile.href)

});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size:40px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Header</h1>
```

Comment: твой пример выводит `null`. В хроме оба свойства `null`: _ss.cssRules || ss.rules_

Comment: вернее не совсем так. Такой подход работает только для стилей описанных в той же странице, либо подключаемых с того же домена

Comment: @Grundy Написал же коментарий! Читайте внимательнее! Там-же встроенный стиль, у него URL быть не может. Но само свойство `href` задано, чему можно убедиться и будет возвращать адрес файла

Comment: Так в чем смысл показывать пример, который не работает? Кроме того, что комментарий плохо заметен, нигде не сказано в каких случаях данный код будет работать.

Comment: Почему не работает? Null говорит о том, что это встроенный стиль, это не ошибка

Comment: Ну так смысл показывать null? В вопросе же речь про файлы шла

Comment: Вы придираетесь